How to Integrating Admob with blazor hybrid app
Is that posible to add Admob to Blazor Hybrid(MAUI + Blazor) application?

About adding Admob to Blazor MAUI, you can refer to this case: MAUI Blazor Hybrid Admob.

While this question technically could use some work in terms of clarity, allow me to still answer it in a broader sense.
A Blazor Hybrid app is still a .NET MAUI app, so yes, you can absolutely do this. How you will do this is a different question. Do you just want to show a little bar ad? Then you will have to take that into account in your layout probably and wrap your BlazorWebView in a Grid or a VerticalStackLayout.
A full page ad should be able to just show, because again, its still just a .NET MAUI app showing a web view.
One thing you can't do is integrate .NET MAUI components inside the BlazorWebView so if you're choosing to make your app fully hybrid (use the web view to cover you full screen and build your app in Blazor) then you should maybe consider using the AdMob web SDK which should work to integrate it in there.
Hope this helps a little bit! I have also created a video about combining .NET MAUI with Blazor Hybrid here: https://youtu.be/2dllz4NZC0I which should hopefully give you some clues as well.

Thank you very much. I will give a try with this way. You may to do specific video on Youtube since there are no resources to integrate Admob with Blazor Hybrid
